# How to erase a value efficiently from a sorted vector?

Tags: c++

Assume that `vec` is a sorted vector of movable and copyable objects. What is the most efficient way to remove all elements that match `value`?

Is this correct and the most efficient way?

```
auto lb = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
vec.erase(lb, std::upper_bound(std::next(lb), vec.end(), value));
```

What is the complexity? (Taking into account any moving required after the erasure).

Comment: A quick note: if you want to have a sorted vector of unique elements, you may want to go for a `std::set`.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Not a duplicate; that question is about removing many elements from an unsorted vector while this question is about removing elements from a sorted vector, presumably one that should stay sorted after the operation. The solution in the linked question will not preserve the relative order of elements.

Comment: @black He mentions that he wants to remove *all* elements that match `value`, which indicates he would want a `multiset` instead.

Comment: @black Assume the elements may not be unique

Comment: Assume the vector may not always be sorted. This is just a general question.

Comment: `std::remove` preservers the order of the elements that were not removed.

Comment: @user2040251 I want to know if there is a more efficient solution than `std::remove` taking into account the fact the vector is sorted.

Comment: @NeilKirk Then it may be more efficient to swap the range you determine with lower_bound and upper_bound with elements at the end of the vector, then erase those. That will be more efficient in most cases than shifting all of the following elements down, though it will of course cause the vector to become un-sorted. The answer depends on whether you need the vector to remain sorted after this operation.

Comment: @Neil: First words in question: _"Assume that `vec` is a sorted vector"_. First words in your comment: _"Assume the vector may not always be sorted"_. o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What I mean is, at this point in time the vector is sorted. But later on in time the vector may not be sorted any more. So I can't just use a set data structure.

Comment: @NeilKirk But do you need the vector to remain sorted after this operation, or is it permissible for the remove operation to cause the vector to become un-sorted? This is an important detail you have left out of your question. A correct answer depends on it.

Comment: @Neil Kirk That's two different questions, with very different answers. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @cdhowie I didn't consider that. I don't mind.

Comment: @MarkB Which two different questions?

Comment: @Neil Kirk You want to erase from a sorted vector, and you want to erase from an unsorted vector. They sound almost the same yet are quite different.

Comment: Either you can assume sortedness and you can use a set, or you can not assume sortedness and this question is pointless (because any solution would be inherently broken in X% of cases). So..

Comment: @MarkB No, I want to erase from a sorted vector. I never stated I want to erase from an unsorted vector. After erasing, additional operations may cause the vector to become unsorted, so I can't use multiset.

Comment: Isn't resorting after removing one element (or a range of equal elements) pretty much neglegible? That's an almost-sorted range. Insertion sort for the win.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Later on in time means after I have erased the elements!

Comment: I apologise for not expressing myself clearly. The vector is always sorted at the time of erasure.

Comment: Must the erase preserve the sorting order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done some brief testing with <strike>three</strike> four different methods of erasing from a sorted container.

```
void erase_v1(std::vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    vec.erase(std::remove(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), value), std::end(vec));
}

void erase_v2(std::vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), value);
    if (lb != std::end(vec) && *lb == value) {
        auto ub = std::upper_bound(lb, std::end(vec), value);
        vec.erase(lb, ub);
    }
}

void erase_v3(std::vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    auto pr = std::equal_range(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), value);
    vec.erase(pr.first, pr.second);
}

// Surt's code, doesn't preserve sorted order
void erase_v4(std::vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    // get the range in 2*log2(N), N=vec.size()
    auto bounds = std::equal_range(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);

    // calculate the index of the first to be deleted O(1)
    auto last = vec.end() - std::distance(bounds.first, bounds.second);

    // swap the 2 ranges O(equals) , equal = std::distance(bounds.first, bounds.last)
    std::swap_ranges(bounds.first, bounds.second, last);

    // erase the victims O(equals)
    vec.erase(last, vec.end());
}
```

Tested with a `std::vector` of 10,000,000 elements, filled with random numbers in the range `[0..9]`, and then sorted (MS Visual C++ 2013).

Erase the value `0` (the front of the container), representative times look like:

```
time=14.3894 size=8999147 // v1, milliseconds and updated container size
time=11.9486 size=8999147 // v2
time=11.5548 size=8999147 // v3
time=1.78913 size=8999147 // v4 (Surt)
```

Erase `5` (the middle of the container):

```
time=12.8223 size=9000844
time=4.89388 size=9000844
time=4.87589 size=9000844
time=1.77284 size=9000844
```

Erase `9` (the end of the container):

```
time=12.64 size=9000820
time=0.00373372 size=9000820
time=0.00339429 size=9000820
time=1.29899 size=9000820
```

Erase `13` (value not in container):

```
time=11.8641 size=10000000
time=0.002376 size=10000000
time=0.00203657 size=10000000
time=0.00220628 size=10000000
```

The `erase/remove` method always iterates over the entire container and is slower, the `lower_bound/upper_bound` and `equal_range` methods are nearly identical over multiple runs. I prefer the last version because it's correct, simpler code, and less typing.

Edit: Timed [Surt's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720032/445976) by request. It is consistently fast at the cost of not preserving sorted order.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, could I get you to time my solution too, I'd like to know the answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, so I see it might pay off to have a couple of if-s to select the right algorithm if the vector is large enough.

Answer (score 6):

A solution that leave the vector unsorted after erase.

```
// get the range in 2*log2(N), N=vec.size()
auto bounds=std::equal_range (vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);  

// calculate the index of the first to be deleted O(1)
auto last = vec.end()-std::distance(bounds.first, bounds.last);

// swap the 2 ranges O(equals) , equal = std::distance(bounds.first, bounds.last)
std::swap_ranges(bounds.first, bounds.last, last);

// erase the victims O(equals)
vec.erase(last, vec.end());
```

`std::remove` is O(N) and this solution also does the fewest writes. If *equals* is near N this might not be so great an idea :)

Comment: Should that be `vec.erase(last, vec.end())`?

Comment: +1 - I think given from the comments that maintaining sorted-ness is not required, this is the best answer.

Comment: The swap_ranges might not be optimal where they overlap, but that might or might not be a problem.

Comment: SG14 is proposing to add `std::unstable_remove` for just this case.

Answer (score 3):

That is not correct in the case that `value` does not actually appear in `vec`. So at the very least you will have to do:

```
auto lb = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
if (lb != vec.end() && *lb == value) {
    vec.erase(lb, std::upper_bound(std::next(lb), vec.end(), value));
}
```

As to the question of most efficient: I believe in the general case, knowing nothing about what happens to be in `vec`, yes. Complexity is still `O(N)` because `erase()` is `O(N)` - you can't really have a non-linear erase if you're erasing like the 2nd element. But in terms of finding the bounds to erase, `O(log N)` is as good as it gets and you got it.

The question of whether `upper_bound()` or just `find_if()` is better for the 2nd part depends completely on how likely you are to have lots of `value`s or not. More likely to have lots, use `upper_bound()`, more likely to be unique, use `find_if()`.

Comment: Good point about the element not being there. The following would also work, as two identical iterators are an empty range. Note the removal of next `vec.erase(lb, std::upper_bound(lb, vec.end(), value));`

Comment: @NeilKirk yep. Probably actually better since one less branch.

Comment: If you are going to call both `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` you might as well just call `std::equal_range` and pass the returned iterator pair to `erase`. You don't even have to test the iterators against `end()`, an empty range will just be a no-op for `erase`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace If you think that is better, please post an answer about it!

Comment: You can erase the elements faster if the vector doesn't have to remain sorted by instead swapping the elements to the end of the vector and then erasing them; this won't require that the following elements be moved down.  Whether or not this is more efficient depends on how many vector elements follow the range you want to remove and the size of the range. For example if the range you want to remove is the first 10 elements and the vector contain 1,000 elements, you can see how swapping the first 10 and last 10 elements then erasing them would be faster than shifting 990 elements down.

Comment: I totally agree with cdhowie here. If the number to be erased starts nearing the original length the idea is not so great but that depends on your vector size and how many ifs you want to add to the code.