# How to erase elements from a vector based on a specific condition in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I have a vector of objects and I want to erase some objects, without re-sorting.

I found some solutions here, but these are based on comparing the vector element to a value. 
[[How to erase a value efficiently from a sorted vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719144/how-to-erase-a-value-efficiently-from-a-sorted-vector][1])

However, I need to erase based on a conditional statement, so I don't think I can use those functions the way they are.

In this example, I have a vector of 3D vectors
I need to remove all elements which have a Z value less than 0;

What I have right now is another vector that is created from an original one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < original_vectors.size(); i++)
        if (original_vectors[i].z > 0)
            new_vectors.push_back(original_vectors[i]);
```

What can I do to simply drop the elements that don't have Z > 0?

Comment: You say you want to *remove all elements which have a Z value less than 0*, but your code sample removes elements which have `Z <= 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), which is the standard way to remove elements from an STL container which support a condition. This code snippet will remove all vector elements for which `predicate` returns true:

```
vector.erase(std::remove_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), predicate), vector.end());
```

A predicate for which checks if `z < 0` is:

```
auto predicate = [](const vec3 &v) { return v.z < 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I chose this answer because it was the most elegant, but I'm sure the other ones are correct.   I had to modify it a bit: vectors.erase(std::remove_if(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), [](const Vector3<float> &v) { return v.z < 0; }), vectors.end());

Answer (score 7):

Use the [erase-remove](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) idiom. You'll need to call [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a lambda expression that returns true when `z < 0`.

```
original_vectors.erase(std::remove_if(original_vectors.begin(),
                                      original_vectors.end(),
                                      [](decltype(original_vectors)::value_type const& elem) {
                                          return elem.z < 0;
                                      },
                       original_vectors.end());
```

Comment: @T.C. available in VS2015 today :)

Comment: @melak Not surprising considering STL proposed it :)

Comment: @melak47, I'd rather them have proper constexpr support.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the boost libraries, a potentially more elegant way to write the remove_if/erase idiom is using boost's [remove_erase_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/remove_erase_if.html).

The code would look something like this:

```
boost::range::remove_erase_if(original_vector,
                              [](vector_element_type t) -> bool {
                                return t.z <= 0;
                             });
```