# Improvement to remove-erase idiom when order need not be preserved

Tags: c++, algorithm

The popular `remove_if`-`erase` idiom preserves the order of the elements kept in the container. I have a case in which I would like to remove some elements, but I don't care about the order of the remaining ones, because they are going to be moved around later on, anyway. I thought, then, that instead of using `remove_if`-`erase`, I can scan the vector and - when an element to remove is found - I can swap it with the last valid element of the vector. I call this idiom `swap`-`erase`, and it can easily be implemented as follows:

```
template<typename Object, typename Condition>
void swap_erase(std::vector<Object>& v, const Condition& condition) {
    // Keeps track to one past the last element we want to keep.
    auto iter_to_last = v.end();

    for(auto it = v.begin(); it < iter_to_last; ++it) {
        // If the erasure condition is fulfilled...
        if(condition(*it)) {
            // Increase by one to the left the "tail" of the
            // vector, made by elements we want to get rid of;
            // Swap the two elements.
            // Rewind the current iterator by 1, so at the
            // next iteration we test the element we just swapped.
            std::iter_swap(it--, --iter_to_last);
        }
    }

    // Erase the elements we pushed at the end of the queue.
    v.erase(iter_to_last, v.end());
}
```

Since there is no need to shift elements, I would expect this code to be consistently faster than `remove_if`-`erase` on vectors which are large, or contain large objects.
However, [a quick benchmark](https://github.com/alberto-santini/cpp-experiments/blob/master/swap-erase/swap-erase-benchmark.cpp) shows that the two [are roughly equivalent](https://github.com/alberto-santini/cpp-experiments/blob/master/swap-erase/example-benchmark-results.txt) when compiled by gcc 7.3.0 with `-Ofast`, on my i7 at 2.6GHz.

Am I wrong in my assumptions, in my implementation, or in the way I am benchmarking?

**Edit**: it turns out I was wrong in my assumption. This is a possible implementation of `remove_if` which clearly shows that it needs not shift any element:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Predicate>
ForwardIterator remove_if(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred) {
    first = std::find_if(first, last, pred);

    if(first == last) {
        return first;
    }

    ForwardIterator result = first;
    ++first;

    for(; first != last; ++first) {
        if(!pred(first)) {
            *result = std::move(*first);
            ++result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing some years ago, ending up with the same result. I suppose it is because of cpu cache.

Comment: I believe the reason for this is that there is noway to tell `v.erase(iter_to_last, v.end());` that you are trying to delete from the end of the vector. So it is treating it as any other call, i.e. `vec.erase(begin_itr, end_itr)` which takes O(n) time.

Comment: Curiously I did the same years ago, and found it was considerable faster, in some case order(s) of magnitude. Except in corner cases where it performed the same.

Comment: @ViktorSehr cache locality should be the same for both methods, I think?

Comment: @VikashKesarwani but the bottleneck should rather be all the shifting going on each time `remove_if` hits, rather than erasing. I agree, however, that it would be nice having an O(1) tail-erase.

Comment: @Surt do you happen to still have the code? I am curious! :-)

Comment: @VikashKesarwani: Erasing at the end takes O(n) time if elements have a non-trivial destructor (`n` elements need to be destroyed, which takes O(n) time). This also applies to containers which preserve references, like linked lists, because each element is a separate allocation. (`std:deque` optimises, though.) For vectors of PODs, however, erasing the end of the vector should be O(1).

Comment: @rici but how does the erase method know that you are deleting at the end of the vector. Have you gone through the implementation.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini: But your algorithm is active in two memory locations, whereas std::remove_if is only active in one

Comment: @vikash: v.erase(a, b) first copies (b, end) to the positions starting at a, and then truncates the vector at the end of the copy. The first part is a no-op if b==end and the second part is O(1) if elements don't need to be destroyed.

Comment: @viktor: how you benchmark will be important since the two algorithms are optimised for different cases. Also, elements with non-trivial destructors will probably show different patterns, particularly if they don't optimise moves (although these days one hopes that is rare).

Comment: @AlbertoSantini, seems I remember the problem wrongly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719144/how-to-erase-a-value-efficiently-from-a-sorted-vector/26720032#26720032, so not that relevant to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption about how `remove_if` works might be wrong. Perhaps you should state it explicitly.

Basically `remove_if` moves each not deleted element at most once, so it is particularly fast if most elements are being deleted. (It might optimise by first scanning over the initial part of the array which is not being deleted, in which case it will also be fast if few elements are being deleted and the first deleted element is near the end.)

Your swap algorithm does one `swap` for each element being deleted, so it is fastest if few elements are being deleted. But `swap` is unnecessary, and unnecessarily slow in some cases since it requires three moves.  You could just *move* the last element over top of the element being deleted, possibly saving two data copies.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong in my assumption that `remove_if` should have a worse complexity than it really has, I am going to update the question writing a possible implementation of `remove_if` which outlines this.